# Am I abusing the flush() call?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a web application where users can create and edit articles. Each article edit creates a new revision. I'm using SQLAlchemy as an ORM.

Now, every time I create an article this is what happens:

```
  # Create the article
  article = Article(...)
  session.add(article)
  session.flush()

  # Create the revision
  revision = Revision(article.id, ...)
  session.add(revision)
  session.flush()

  # Set article's `current_revision_id` field to the revision's id
  article.current_revision_id = revision.id

  session.commit()
```

The reason I have to call flush() everytime is so I can get the IDs for the Article and Revision. Both the Article and Revision cannot be committed to the database until they have references to each other's ids.

My question is whether this is a sane thing to do. Is it possible that if many people are creating an article at the same time, the allocated IDs from the flush() calls become unsynced? Is this acceptable as a "transaction"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using IDs in your code, use the [**relationship system**](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) of SQLAlchemy.

```
article = Article(...)
revision = Revision(article, ...)
article.current_revision = revision
session.add(article)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Doing this gave me a CircularDependencyError. I believe this is because an Article has many revisions. But its revisions also point back to the Article.

Comment: It is indeed not a simple case. I think you need `post_update=True` in the `current_revision` relationship

Comment: Wow I've been trying to find the documentation on "Rows that point to themselves / Mutually Dependent Rows" for ages. Not only did your post_update=True comment work, but it helped me find that page!! If you don't mind me asking, should I prefer passing around and setting model objects rather than ids like in your example? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, I'd only access ID columns if you want to use the ID for something such as an URL.